# Looking for insight! Relation between the set of increasing sequences of naturals and transcendental numbers.

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking for a way to categorize irrational numbers between 0 and 1 for which the decimal expression contains only 0s and 1s (numbers that look like that : x=0.101101001101..., non periodic and infinite)

Each number in this set can be linked to an increasing sequence of natural numbers corresponding to the position of the "1"s in x.
This relationship is not a bijection as some sequences give rational numbers.

I thought a good way to better understand this set of numbers is to study the set of sequences that it corresponds to. So my question is:
Does the set of increasing sequences of natural numbers have some interesting properties or has interesting subsets that could help me understand the set of numbers I'm relating it to?

EDIT 1: I didn't specify the relationship with transcendental numbers that I mentioned in the title of the question:

All irrational algebraic numbers are conjectured to be disjunctive. As the expansion of the numbers x in the set I described contain only 0s and 1s, they are not disjunctive, thus should be transcendental (if the conjecture is true).

One comment pointed out the relationship with the Liouville number, which is based on the sequence Un = n!. If you read the proof (or watch it in the wonderful "Mathologer" Youtube channel) you would understand that any sequence that is faster than "n!" would lead to a transcendetal number.
We could also have similar results with sequences that are slower than n! but fast enough to be proven transcendental in the same way as the Liouville number.

We are then left with the rest of the increasing sequences, all arithmetic sequences lead to a rational number. Same thing with any arithmetic sequences to wich we add periodic "jumps" of any finite length (like the sequence 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11..., the corresponding number is 0.110110110...=110/999).

Comment: I doubt that considering these increasing sequences helps to better understand those numbers.

Comment: Your title ("transcendental") and body ("irrational") conflict.

Comment: If the sequence increases fast enough , often such a number can be proven to be a Liouville-number , special numbers that are always transcendental.

Comment: If you intend to keep all such irrational numbers (and not the smaller set of all such transcendental numbers), then one property the set has (doesn't characterize the set) is that the set is the collection of non-endpoints of a perfect nowhere dense set of Lebesgue measure zero (with, I think, Hausdorff & box/Minkowski & packing dimension $0.2).$

Comment: Your set, by mapping it to the base 2 numbers, has the same structure as all irrational numbers between 0 and 1.  Alternatively, if you just look at the differences in adjacent integers in your sequence, you just need it to be aperiodic and infinite.